# Is there a dplyr workflow to take non-standard file names and force them into having structure?

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe, grepl

I'm reading in files sent by someone else. The files have a loose general structure, but it is inconsistent. I'm trying to take the file names, process them using dplyr, and create new file names that conform to my own imposed standard.

The crop will always be 'Corn', which I was trying to use as my anchor for deciding if a filename is funky. I've tried using separate, gsub, grepl, and ifelse statements, but they are all clumsy and don't quite work. I'm new-ish to dplyr (and stackoverflow), and need some guidance. Thanks for the help!

Example filenames

```
dat <- tibble(filename = c("2017.Ames-Corn-early.out", 
                    "2017.Cobs-Corn.out",
                    "2017.MuscCorn_lowN.out"))
```

First attempt:

```
dat %>%
  # Separate, it is inconsistent, needs work 
  separate(filename, into = c("year", "site", "crop", "trt", "other"))
```

Desired structure, in tibble form:

```
dat2 <- tribble(
  ~year, ~ site, ~crop, ~trt,
  2017,   "Ames", "Corn", "early",
  2017,   "Cobs", "Corn", NA,
  2017,   "Musc", "Corn", "lowN")
dat2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a partial answer. I don't know a good way to split at the capital letters but there's probably a simple regex way.

```
library(tidyverse)
dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(filename = str_remove(filename, "\\.out")) %>%
  separate(filename,  
           c("year", "site", "crop", "trt"), 
           sep = "[[:punct:]]")

> dat2
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  year  site     crop  trt  
  <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>
1 2017  Ames     Corn  early
2 2017  Cobs     Corn  NA   
3 2017  MuscCorn lowN  NA
```

Comment: Nice, though `".out"` should probably be `"\\.out"` though as the `.` means 'any character' in regex.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. The snakecase package seems to break things up. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snakecase/vignettes/caseconverters.html